# Avoiding inheritance, how could I give my class a default creation dependency?

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, php-5.5

Sometimes the best way to ask a question, is by my own attempt at solving it...

Say I have a class:

```
use App/Jedi;
use App/Interfaces/Teacher;   // <-- Jedi is an implementation of Teacher

class AnakinSkywalker implements Apprenticeable;
{
    private $teacher;
    public $lightSaberColor = "blue";

    public function __construct(Jedi $teacher){  // <-- default Teacher
        $this->setTeacher($teacher);         
    }        

    public function setTeacher(Teacher $teacher){  // <-- can change later here
         $this->teacher = $teacher; 
    }

    public function printHowManyCanTeach(){
        echo $teacher->count();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Lots of places in my app I use it like this:

```
$character = new AnakinSkywalker;
echo $character->howManyCanTeach();    // prints "Many masters"
...
```

But one day I decide somewhere specific in my app I need to do this instead:

```
$sith = new Sith;   // <-- Sith is an implementation of Teacher
$characher = (new AnakinSkywalker)->setTeacher($sith);
echo $character->howManyCanTeach();  // prints "Always two there are, no more, no less"
...
```

Is this a proper, testable, and loosely coupled solution to give an object a default dependency with the ability to change it out later? If not, why, and what could I do to accomplish this?

Comment: Shouldnt Anakin be an object and character a class? And besides, do what feels right to you. Programming is not an exact science

Comment: Oh, my example choice was not perfect there, sorry! But actually Anakin is the name of a unique implementation of Apprenticeable. Sure, perhaps I could later *extend* Anakin from a Character base class. But for this example this is not what I'm asking. I am creating many of these classes for holding properties and methods that follow Apprenticeable. Character is just a variable name.

Comment: Yeah, ideally I want to put the `__constructor` and `setTeacher` methods in a **Trait**(for a tad bit even more flexibility! and DRY) and just drop it in every class that needs this setup. I avoid inheritance with this solution, yet I still get that advantage of a default setup that inheritance brings. I don't like to be unnecessarily verbose and drop an instance of Teacher in every time I use the class, when maybe 99% of the time right now the Teacher will be Jedi.

Comment: Actually @ItayMoav-Malimovka the idea that later sometime I might want to add a base class called `character` actually is a another great point my question brings out. Regarding flexibility, it would be nice to keep that option open (since PHP is single inheritance), so even more the need to do something like I propose in my question.

Comment: Once traits where introduced, PHP is no longer single inheritance language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by accepting null as the parameter, and creating the dependency if it is null:

```
class AnakinSkywalker implements Apprenticeable {

    public function __construct(Teacher $teacher = null) {
        if ($teacher == null) {
            $teacher = new Jedi();
        }
        $this->teacher = $teacher;
    }
}
```

Yes, this creates coupling between the two classes, but that is not always wrong.